# How to acquire Dark Matter?

Tags: atmospheric-science, dark-matter

I want to acquire some [Dark Matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_matter) as is mentioned in [this paper](https://board.flatassembler.net/topic.php?p=212632) and I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to use helium balloon to reach to the Dark-Matter-sphere?
2. What type of ceramic or other material is needed to collect Dark-Matter?

Comment: I have acquired a kilo of dark matter but sorry I can't sell it as it is illegal to do so. You should talk to American army they might help you.

Answer (score 5):

You're out of luck. There's 1) [almost no dark matter in the solar system](https://www.forbes.com/sites/startswithabang/2018/03/24/ask-ethan-if-dark-matter-is-everywhere-why-havent-we-detected-it-in-our-solar-system/#6f9ce1b352fc), and 2) even if you could get your hands on a dark matter particle, you can't confine it - it would fall out of any container made of any ceramic, because it doesn't interact with the material.

Comment: Clearly you haven’t read the linked paper. The OP wants to collect the matter, of which angels are made. He needs it to be able to cure cancer with it.

Comment: @safesphere you actually downloaded and opened that file? I salute your courage.

Comment: @safesphere I could not download the file, it must have been removed from that site.